# Error loading "oligo" Bioconductor package

Tags: r, package, bioinformatics, bioconductor

On Windows XP, After updating to R 2.15.3 and updating all libraries, I was no longer able to load the "oligo" package from BioConductor.

To recreate:

```
source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R") #install the BioC installer
biocLite("oligo")  #download and install the oligo package
library("oligo") #attempt to load
```

Gets the following error:

```
Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 
unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-2.15.3/library/affxparser/libs/i386/affxparser.dll':
LoadLibrary failure:  The specified procedure could not be found.
```

The file it mentions, "C:/Program Files/R/R-2.15.3/library/affxparser/libs/i386/affxparser.dll", is right where it's supposed to be.

sessionInfo() returns:

```
R version 2.15.3 (2013-03-01)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] Biobase_2.18.0      oligoClasses_1.20.0 BiocGenerics_0.4.0



loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] affyio_1.26.0        BiocInstaller_1.8.3  Biostrings_2.26.3   
[4] bit_1.1-10           codetools_0.2-8      ff_2.2-11           
[7] foreach_1.4.0        GenomicRanges_1.10.7 IRanges_1.16.6      
[10] iterators_1.0.6      parallel_2.15.3      stats4_2.15.3       
[13] tools_2.15.3         zlibbioc_1.4.0
```

.libPaths() returns:

```
[1] "C:/Program Files/R/R-2.15.3/library"
[2] "C:/Program Files/RStudio/R/library"
```

Comment: What happens if you try: `biocLite("affxparser")`

Comment: Exactly the same: Message says affxparser installs successfully, then when I try to load it using library("affxparser"), I get the same error message.

Comment: affxparser is known to often not work on Windows XP.